# Validate XML against XSD and enrich with validation results

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

I'm building a java tool to validate an xml document and build an html report containing the input data and validation results.
I think that a possible way is:

1. validate XML with XSD
2. enrich the XML with validation results
3. transform the enriched XML in the final HTML report (this point is not object of the question)

First and foremost, is this a valid approach? Or there are more suitable ways to get those things done in java?

If this is is a viable solution, how can i implement step 2?

For example, if I start from this input document:

```
<parent>
    <child id="a correct id" type="a correct type"/>
    <child id="an incorrect id" type="an incorrect type"/>
</parent>
```

How can I produce an enriched output document like that:

```
<parent>

    <child id="a correct id" type="a correct type">
        <results>
            <result>id is correct</result>
            <result>type is correct</result>
        </results>
    </child>

    <child id="an incorrect id" type="an incorrect type">
        <results>
            <result>id is NOT correct</result>
            <result>type is NOT correct</result>
        </results>
    </child>

</parent>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, there are many ways of going about this.  There are other tools like [schematron](http://www.schematron.com/validators.html) that provide languages for describing validation results, and the ability to transform the results of validation into pretty HTML.   There are numerous java packages that actually do schema validation, so most of what you're trying to accomplish should be "glue code".   Make sure you don't attempt to do schema validation in your java code.

So next, I'm not sure what your requirements are for wanting to transform the original XML file after validation.  Usually you'd dump a validation result set as a separate file.  Does the schema for the original XML permit your additions that you're putting in?

In general, if you wanted to transform the original input, you could go about this by writing an XSLT program that takes the validation results file, and the original source file, and then transforms the original file using those validation results.  But I don't recommend that because I think your situation might call for a different design that doesn't transform the original file, unless you have more requirements you want to go into more depth about.

Another option would be straightforward DOM manipulation.  After validation, you could [load the DOM for the input document](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/), manipulate it, then write it back to the same original file.

But seriously -- before you adopt any approach for step 2, make sure that your requirements really call for it.

Answer (score 1):

One approach worth exploring:  Xerces-J provides access to the post-schema-validation infoset (PSVI), and can in fact serialize it as XML.  For small documents, at least, you may find that XML representation of the PSVI suffices for your purposes.

The PSVI representation made available by Xerces-J (and by xsv) is not, it should be said, anything like an annotated copy of the input.  But it can be transformed into a form like the one you show using normal XML processing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm returning to this question after I got some deeper understanding and experience of XSD and XSLT and eventually built my project on that knowledge.

My original question had some misleading points.

My objective was to process an XML with the ONLY objective to produce a corresponding HTML report, containing the XML data in a readable form along with the "validation" results against a set of business rules.

My wrong assumption was that I should necessarily have to validate the XML against an XSD, but that brought me some significant challenges in development:

- XSD 1.0 did not fit completely my business rules. So I had to switch to XSD 1.1
- then I had to set up an XSD 1.1 compliant validator in java (Xerces2J)
- and finally I started thinking on how to build a fine-grained validator based on those premises.

It was at that time that I realized that this process was a little overkill: what I really needed was just a TRANSFORMATION from XML to HTML: the fine-grained validation could have been done inside the transformation process, all together with an XSLT.

To answer my own question in the most generic form:
I would still use XSD for a very basic preliminary validation, and then use XSLT to check for more complex validation rules and enrich the XML.

This is the XSLT to transform the source xml of my own question into the result (still XML).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="parent">

    <xsl:for-each select="child">
        <xsl:call-template name="processChildren"/>
    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

<!-- this template processes the children nodes, applying a sample test clause  -->
<xsl:template name="processChildren">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />

    <results>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(@id,'incorrect')">
            <result>id is NOT correct</result>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <result>id is correct</result>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(@type,'incorrect')">
            <result>type is NOT correct</result>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <result>type is correct</result>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </results>

     </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- this template copy the contents of the node unaltered -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```